# Python 2.7: Themed "common dialog" tkinter interfaces via Ttk?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

Python 2.7 (32-bit) Windows: We're experimenting with Python 2.7's support for themed Tkinter (`ttk`) for simple GUI's and have come away very impressed!! The one area where the new theme support seems to have come up short is how OS specific common dialogs are wrapped.

Corrected: In other words, the `MessageBox` and `ColorChooser` common dialogs have "ugly" looking Win 95 style blocky looking buttons vs. the themed (rounded/gradient) buttons that normally show up on these common dialogs under XP, Vista, and Windows 7. (I'm testing on all 3 platforms with identical, un-themed results).

Note: The filedialog common dialogs (`askopenfilename`, `askopenfilenames`, `asksaveasfilename`, `askdirectory`) are all properly themed.

```
import tkMessageBox as messagebox
messagebox.showinfo()

import tkColorChooser as colorchooser
color = colorchooser.askcolor( parent=root, title='Customize colors' )
```

Any ideas on what's required to get Tkinter's `MessageBox` and `ColorChooser` common dialogs to be OS theme compatible (at least under Windows XP or higher)?

Comment: This is a great catch. I'm going to bring this to the Bug Tracker at Python and see if we can make some headway.

Comment: Rafe: Thank you for updating the Python Bug Tracker with this problem. I would be more than happy to help correct this problem. I'm not sure what I can contribute code wise, but I would be happy to test any code fixes on multiple versions of Windows, eg. XP, Vista, Windows 7.

Comment: Here's a link to the issue, you can always look at the source and see if there's a way to correct the source. The way things work is, while you can't commit code unilaterally, anyone can write patches and have them looked at. http://bugs.python.org/issue10171

Comment: An editorial bit: to format inline strings a code put them in backquotes and to format a long piece of code indent it by four spaces. Your edit broke the formatting I did in the earlier edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is mainly correct. I do see what you are referring to in the `messagebox` and the `colorchooser`. However, my filedialogs all seem to have properly rounded buttons, etc.

My recommendation for you on making the messagebox is to create your own messagebox using the `TopLevel` widget, and then define what you need on it and the appropriate behavior for the different buttons (it's definitely a bit harder than just using a messagebox, but if you really need the new style buttons, it'll work).

I don't think you can hack together a solution for the `colorchooser` problem, however.

I though for a minute that perhaps Python 3.1 had fixed this problem, but sadly, I tried and that isn't the case. I suppose if you need the user to pick a color, the buttons will have to be ugly.

Comment: Rafe: Yes, you are correct ... the filedialogs DO render as expected with support for themed (rounded) buttons. The lack of theme support appears to be limited to the messagebox and colorchooser dialogs.

Comment: I've also noticed the following oddity: All the filedialogs (and the colorchooser) display relative to the upper left corner of the parent window ... EXCEPT the askdirectory() dialog which centers itself on the desktop.

Comment: @Malcolm: that's pretty strange. I don't think I would ever notice that independently.

Comment: I'm going to start a new thread to discuss the odd behavior of how Tkinter common dialogs position themselves on the display.

Comment: Rafe: I updated my original question to correct my misstatement about the filedialogs not being themed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

An option to get better looking dialog boxes is to compile your script to an executable using `pyinstaller`. I explain this more thouroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792008/python-tkinter-ttk-themed-message-box/34776309#34776309).

tl;dr, it appears that compiling with `pyinstaller` allows you to have dialog boxes with the style of the currently running OS, but not custom styles.